# Angularjs 1.5 component with typescript not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-components

I have created angularjs 1.5 component using typescript but it is not working and when I say it is not working it's binding not working at all. I can see the the data in my console when it fire $onInit function but it never puts any of that data on screen. This is my first shot at typescript and will really apprecuate if anyone can point me in right direction?

my component code is below

```
class Users implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public bindings: any;
    public controller: any;
    public template: string;
    public templateUrl: string;
    public transclude: boolean;
    public controllerAs: string;

    constructor() {
        this.controller = UsersController;
        this.templateUrl = "Template/Index?feature=users&template=users";
        this.transclude = false;
        this.controllerAs = "vm";
    }
}


class UsersController {
    public name: string;
    public test: string;
    public Users: any[];

    static $inject: string[] = ["$http", "repository.user"];

    constructor(private $http: any, private RepositoryUser: any) {
    }

    public $onInit(): void {
        this.RepositoryUser.getUsers().then(function (response) {
            this.Users = response.data;
            console.dir(this.Users);
        });
    }

    public setUser(id: number, value: any): void {
        this.Users[this.Users.indexOf(value)] = value;

    }
}

angular.module("app.users").component("users", new Users());
```

and my html is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ng-form>
            <h2>Users</h2>

            <div ng-repeat="model in vm.Users track by $index" class="row top10">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <a ui-sref="user-details({ id: model.id })"><strong ng-bind="model.name"></strong></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="vm.selectedId=model.id">Select</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ng-form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax : https://blogs.infinitesquare.com/posts/web/creer-un-component-angularjs-en-typescript
The post is in French but you could just read the sample code.

Let me know if you have more questions.